# XML to ePub Transformation using XSLT and Java plugin

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am doing xml to 'xhtml(epub) transformation' using XSLT and Java plugin. I want to transform video and audio as well and my code already done image transformation. But when we transform video and audio, we should get the path of image folder in xml and set it to xhtml. So I want to know, how to get the path from xml's media folder and set it to xhtml  folder. I have used java for image optimise.I have added input, output and XSLT files.In the output image has absolute src. But Image and audio have relative path.  I want to get absolute path to audio and video as well.If you have any idea, please show me.Thank you
input
`<tps:section id="6B061FF1-87FA-014D-B658-39BFB91EB83F" type="BOARDSHORTS">
        <tps:fieldSet name="Minor" value="dcsdv"/>
        <tps:context id="727803A4-F1A9-DE4C-9EA7-140E238A3ABA" type="Table-Wrap">
            <tps:image comment=" JPG Image" ref="images/2.jpg"/>
            <tps:p type="Normal"/>
        </tps:context>
        <tps:p type="Normal"/>
        <tps:context id="727803A4-F1A9-DE4C-9EA7-140E238A3ABB" type="Table-Wrap">
            <tps:video comment=" MP4 Video" ref="videos/3.mp4"/>
            <tps:p type="Normal"/>
        </tps:context>
        <tps:p type="Normal"/>
        <tps:context id="727803A4-F1A9-DE4C-9EA7-140E238A3ABC" type="Table-Wrap">
            <tps:audio comment=" MP3 Audio" ref="audios/4.mp3"/>
            <tps:p type="Normal"/>
        </tps:context>
        <tps:p type="Normal"/>
    </tps:section>`

output

```
`<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>c2e</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/generated.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body id="c2e">
    <div class="Table-Wrap"> 
      <img alt=" JPG Image" src="/Library/Application Support/Typefi/FileStore/cxml2e/2016-07-20 09.31.11/images/2.jpg"/>  
      <p class="Normal"/> 
    </div>
    <p class="Normal"/>
    <div class="Table-Wrap"> 
      <video alt=" MP4 Video" src="videos/3.mp4"/>  
      <p class="Normal"/> 
    </div>
    <p class="Normal"/>
    <div class="Table-Wrap"> 
      <audio alt=" MP3 Audio" src="audios/4.mp3"/>  
      <p class="Normal"/> 
    </div>
    <p class="Normal"/>
  </body>`
```

XSLT part

```
`<xsl:template match="c:image">
        <img src="{@ref}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="f:get-image-alt(.)"/>
        </img>
    </xsl:template>




    <xsl:function name="f:get-image-alt" as="attribute()?">
        <xsl:param name="image" as="element(c:image)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="comment" select="string($image/@comment)" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="file-name" select="f:get-image-filename($image)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="result" as="attribute()?">
            <xsl:if test="($comment ne '')">
                <xsl:attribute name="alt" select="$comment"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="f:get-image-filename" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="image" as="element(c:image)"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="tokenize($image/@ref, '/')[last()]"/>
    </xsl:function>

 <!--  -->


    <xsl:template match="c:video">
        <video src="{@ref}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="f:get-video-alt(.)"/>
        </video>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:function name="f:get-video-alt" as="attribute()?">
        <xsl:param name="video" as="element(c:video)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="comment1" select="string($video/@comment)" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="file-name1" select="f:get-video-filename($video)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="result" as="attribute()?">
            <xsl:if test="($comment1 ne '')">
                <xsl:attribute name="alt" select="$comment1"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="f:get-video-filename" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="video" as="element(c:video)"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="tokenize($video/@ref, '/')[last()]"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="c:audio">
        <audio src="{@ref}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="f:get-audio-alt(.)"/>
        </audio>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:function name="f:get-audio-alt" as="attribute()?">
        <xsl:param name="audio" as="element(c:audio)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="comment1" select="string($audio/@comment)" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="file-name1" select="f:get-audio-filename($audio)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="result" as="attribute()?">
            <xsl:if test="($comment1 ne '')">
                <xsl:attribute name="alt" select="$comment1"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="f:get-audio-filename" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="audio" as="element(c:audio)"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="tokenize($audio/@ref, '/')[last()]"/>
    </xsl:function>`
```

Comment: Please show some code and xml snippets, how do you try to access the videos in the xslt? Where are you supposed to get the path from? Please edit your question to show this relevant information.

Comment: Hi stefan, I have added relevant details and it's really thankful if you can give me any idea.

Comment: Very good. Now one thing would be missing - what is wrong with your code? In what way does the result that you get differ from what you want? If you add that it will be the easiest for xslt experts to make out the error.

Comment: The thing is in the output, image has absalute path but audio and video did not have absalute path (It has relative path) . I want to know how to get path from relevant folder using java plugin.